# What is the difference between semantic segmentation, object detection and instance segmentation?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection

I'm fairly new at computer vision and I've read an explanation at a [medium post](https://engineering.matterport.com/splash-of-color-instance-segmentation-with-mask-r-cnn-and-tensorflow-7c761e238b46), however it still isn't clear for me how they truly differ.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

- ***Object Detection*** : is the technology that is related to computer vision and image processing. Its aim? detect objects in an image.
- ***Semantic Segmentation*** : is a technique that detects , for each pixel , the object category it belongs to. All object categories ( labels ) must be known to the model.
- ***Instance Segmentation*** : same as Semantic Segmentation, but dives a bit deeper, it identifies , for each pixel, the object instance it belongs to. The main difference is that it differentiates between two objects with the same label.

Here's an example of the main difference.

[image: Differences]

In the second image where **Semantic Segmentation** is applied, the **category** ( **chair** ) is the output class, all chairs are colored the same. In the third image, the **Instance Segmentation**, goes a step further and separates the instances ( the chairs ) from one another in addition to identifying the category ( chair ) in the first step.

Hope this clears it up for you a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You've clarified it for me! To make sure I understand, could I say that both type of segmentations are object detection techniques and that instance is a "higher form" of segmentation, since it does not only segment an object from others categories, but also between each instance of its own category?

Comment: Exactly, thats it!

Answer (score 1):

Instance segmentation:

- The combination annotation of target detection and semantic segmentation.
- The target detection comes first, and then each pixel is labeled (semantic segmentation).

Compared to the image above, we take the person as the target objection for example:

- Semantic segmentation does not distinguish different instances in the same category (all people are marked red)
- Instance segmentation distinguishes different instances of the same category (different people are distinguished by different colors)

I recommend you to have a look at this article: [What is Semantic Segmentation, Instance Segmentation, Panoramic segmentation](https://becominghuman.ai/what-is-semantic-segmentation-instance-segmentation-panoramic-segmentation-3bbb03856c12).